# Total derivatives for a linear function

Tags: derivatives

my teacher say:

if $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to  \mathbb{R}^n$ is linear then $D f(a)=f$ for every $a \in  \mathbb{R}^n$, because

$f(x)-f(a)-f(x-a)=0=o(|x-a|)$

now, is this mean any linear function $f$ his total derivative equal to $f$ ?

but in another lecture he say:

the total derivative of this function:
$f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to  \mathbb{R}^2$ , $(x,y) \to (x+y, x-y)$

is

$D f(x,y)=J_f(x,y) =\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\ 
1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$

I think in this example $D f(x,y)$ is not equal to $f$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your professor's example, Df(x,y) is indeed f(x,y). We have simply rewritten $f(x,y)$ in the form of a matrix.

Have you seen the theorem, perhaps in your linear algebra class, about the matrix of a linear transformation with respect to a basis? It states that the $i^{th}$ column of the matrix representing a linear transformation is the image of the $i^{th}$ basis vector.

In this case, we are taking the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ to be $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$. As such, $f(e_1) = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ and $f(e_2) = \begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$. This gives us that the matrix of $f(x,y)$ is $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}$.

Note further that $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&-1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}x+y\\x-y\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: I understand now, Thank you so much.